# How to migrate from virtualenv to buildout?

Tags: python, virtualenv, buildout

I'm attempting to move a project from `virtualenv` to `buildout`, but I don't think I've grasped the whole concept of `buildout`. All the tutorials I've found discuss `buildout` in the context of using it with `Zope`, which I'm not using and therefore can't see how to continue.

My file structure with `virtualenv` is as follows:

```
myapp/
  app.py
```

Which is run using `/path/to/venvs/myapp/bin/python /path/to/myapp/script.py`.

With `buildout`, my file structure is:

```
myapp/
  app.py
  bootstrap.py
  buildout.cfg
```

Running `python bootstrap.py` and `bin/buildout` gives me these additional files:

```
myapp/
  bin/
    buildout
  eggs/
    setuptools-0.6c12dev_r80622-py2.6.egg
    tornado-1.0.1-py2.6.egg
  parts/
```

At this point I'm unsure how to "run" my app.

Advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following recipe will, install tornado as an egg and create a python and myapp script in the bin directory with the correct search path to find the tornado egg.

```
[buildout] 
parts = python 
eggs = tornado 
extra-paths = ${buildout:directory}

[python] 
recipe = zc.recipe.egg 
interpreter = python 
eggs = ${buildout:eggs} 
entry-points = myapp=app:main 
extra-paths = ${buildout:extra-paths}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Buildout](http://www.buildout.org/) and [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) are actually tangentially related. Buildout is really about the deployment of software in a constrained and controlled fashion, where virtualenv is about encapsulating the environment that python software runs within. Buildout provides what virtualenv does within itself, and then wraps a bit more around it.

Think of buildout as the recipe set of how to take your code and lay it down onto a remote system ready to be run. Some of that process starts with creating a clean sandbox (which is what virtualenv can provide as well) - and then adding in libraries, pieces, and parts as you need.

I'm not a buildout expert, but I'd expect your python main code to show up under "bin" in your directory structure, and that you'd be somehow invoking it from there.

Answer (score 0):

In our project, we don't use Zope either. We took the time to write an introduction for students on how to organize (and distribute through PyPI) their code using `zc.buildout` and standard python packaging tools. It is maybe useful to whoever reads this thread: http://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/docs/releases/v1.2.2/sphinx/html/OrganizeYourCode.html